# Is overclocking RAM worth it?

Tags: memory, overclocking

I am going to purchase a motherboard that supports up to DDR3 2400(O.C.).  I have seen things saying that overclocking RAM is not worth it.  Is it worth it to buy memory that is rated for DDR3 2400 and overclock it or should I just buy DDR3 1600 (the highest non-overclocked memory rating that the motherboard supports)?

Are there noticeable performance gains when you overclock to DDR3 2400? (Note that I have already gone for more obvious performance gains such as using an SSD).

The use case for this machine will be gaming and programming.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

On the flip side of the dire warnings, my experience with overclocking is that the performance boosts are *rarely* worth the numerous headaches that a less-than-stable system cause (a very common issue with overclocked ram.)

Best way I can describe the difference; buy an 80 watt lightbulb, and live with it for a week.  The swap out the 75 watt bulb.  You might notice a *teeny* tiny difference for the first five minutes, but the reality is it's about the same darn thing.

There's far more noticable performance boost by running SSDs in a raid 0 configuration (or some derivative) and the beefiest clocked GPU you can afford, with a suitable cpu coming in behind.  The *amount* of RAM can improve your experience, meaning there can be fewer occasions that the game has to read data from disk.

Comment: Thanks.  Glad to know that my gut feeling of not overclocking the memory was correct.

Answer (score 1):

Though there might get some gain in performance but since you already have SSD and it is a gaming rig, I believe you already have plenty of RAM , its not worth the risk.

Overclocking might void your warranty and there is a risk of damage to it and other components (read fire). You don't really want your rig catching fire for sake of few more fps. Check this [link](http://www.mmo-champion.com/threads/1073247-Overclocking-RAM-vs-CPU) for a more detailed information on expected gain.

Comment: Fire?? How does that happen?

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend against doing this. It is risky and fire, like [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gw-rUCwLoQ0) can happen. It will void your warranty for sure, and it can come out quite terrible. A burning computer would be horrific. I would suggest overclocking your CPU, or getting a better Mother Board if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you have it cooled properly, you might see some performance increases, but there are a lot of risks and for most people it's not worth it.